# Google Analytics PHP API not returning data when using today as start/end date

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Here is some of my code.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($ga_app_name);

$private_key = file_get_contents($google_cert_path);

$client->setAssertionCredentials(
    new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $client_email,
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
        $private_key
    )
);

$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setAccessType('offline_access');

$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$response = $service->data_ga->get(
            'ga:' . $profile_id,
            $start_date,    // YYYY-MM-DD
            $end_date,      // YYYY-MM-DD
            $metrics,       // comma-separated list of metrics (ie ga:visits,ga:pageviews)
            $params
        );

$data = $response->getRows();
```

Where `$start_date` and `$end_date` are today's date.

`$metrics` is set to `'ga:pageViews'` and `$params` is an array with one entry - `'max-results' => 100`.

`$data` returns an empty array.

Comment: Google Analytics does not work in realtime (unless you use the realtime API which will return data only for the last 30 minutes and only a limited set of fields). Most likely you do not get data for today because it has not been processe yet.

Comment: @EikePierstorff that is not completely true. you can set start date and end date to today and get data back.  The data wont be accurate.   but there will be some data.   try it https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: @DaImTo, thank you for that great debugging tool!
Looking at the empty results, I start to wonder if my Google Analytics settings are okay...

Comment: Is there data on the website?  Remember it takes a while for a new account to start recording data.

Comment: I just checked and there is data. I'm not sure I am handling things properly. I am trying to track visits of sub-domains. I can see that there are now a few hits and like you said, it probably takes time for it to register properly.

Comment: @EikePierstorff could also have been the time of day.  normally takes an hour or so for stuff to filter though so 1 am there may be nothing there yet.   No matter what checking the data for today is always a bad idea.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I just checked and it works with both pageviews and pageViews.
The dimensions is passed in the $params variable and is optional. The metrics is the one that is required.
The link that DalmTo gave earlier - https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ really helped me debug the situation.

Comment: @PeterPetrov, I confused this with the old gapi-google-analytics-php-interface (which required a dimension although it's not be required by the API).  Nevermind.